# Nested Propertygroups and CollectionProperty

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to create a sort of tree of nested Propertygroups, Where each Propertygroup can contain a list, or collectionproperty of new propertygroups that are the same type as itself.
This seems impossible to define, as you can't register a collectionproperty before the propertygroup type is defined. I've tried to use inheritance to solve it, but am getting nowhere.
Here's my code:

````
class DivisionProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    size: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Size",
        default=0,
        unit='LENGTH',
    )

bpy.utils.register_class(DivisionProps)

class DivisionProps(DivisionProps):
    divisions: bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type = DivisionProps)
    
bpy.utils.register_class(DivisionProps)
```
````

Comment: Hello ! It is not possible, and I would say it is not advisable anyway, you may want to think of a different way to structure your data. If you really want to do it like that, you need to maintain a constant ID key (integer, string) per property group instance and refer to it in your property group definition. You also need to maintain a list of all your property group instances and when you want to fetch a linked PG you want to iterate over your list of PGs and find the one which ID key matches the one that's stored in the property group instance.

Comment: Interesting, so you're suggesting instead of having an actual hierarchical structure, to use a "soft hierarchy", where all items are at the same level, they merely have a property pointing to another one as parent?
But I'm inclined to agree, Blender seems very lacking in scripting your own tree structures (UI for this will be a mess too), so this will be my best bet.

Comment: Well you can have a regular tree like structure, just not self-referencing items :)

Comment: Sure, I'm just in the mindset of Qt-like tree structures where you do iterate like this, it's mentally a bit easier for me...
There is some hope though: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/ZQcbbc/?sorting=hot#